# Pick on someone your own size

Tags: prepositions

> Wilbur should leave his little brother alone and pick on someone his own size.

I couldn't understand  structure of the phrase '' pick on someone your own size'' .I thought there should be a preposition like ''in''or ''with'' between ''someone'' and ''your own size'' like ;

> > Wilbur should leave his little brother alone and pick on someone **in** your own size.

Comment: "In" is not possible, but "of" is OK, as in "pick on someone (of) your own size".

Comment: What about ''with ''?

Comment: No: only "of" is possible, though most speakers would not use a preposition at all.

Comment: I think now is an appropriate time to tell you that I bought a Catwoman suit in your size.

I thought to use “in” based on the example above.

Comment: That's a different kind of construction. "something in a certain size" is quite natural, but "someone in a certain size" is not.

Comment: I got it you mean it may seem grammatical but is not natural.

Comment: Garments are made _in_ different sizes. People may be _the same size_ as one another. By the way, it should be "Wilbur should pick on someone _his_ own size".

Comment: Buy shirts labeled "tall", which are usually available only in large or XL but if you are in that size group.... '' In '' is used in this sentence. Is it different structure?

Comment: @Foreignstudent: Yes. See Kate Bunting's comment